# expected unqualified-id before '.' token arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino, header-files

I am getting this error:

> In function 'void loop()': headers_stepper_test:12: error: expected
>   unqualified-id before '.' token expected unqualified-id before '.' token

in this code:

```
#include "StepperMotor.h"

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
StepperMotor(8,9);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


  void StepperMotor.moveDegrees(-180);
  delay(1000);

}
```

The cpp library file:

```
#include "Arduino.h"

StepperMotor::StepperMotor(int pin1, int pin2)
{
    dirPin=pin1;
    pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
      stepperPin=pin2;
      pinMode(stepperPin,OUTPUT);

}

void StepperMotor::stepDegrees(bool dir, int steps);
{
 digitalWrite(dirPin,dir);
 delay(50);
 for(int i=0;i<steps;i++){
   digitalWrite(stepperPin, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(800);
   digitalWrite(stepperPin, LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(800);
}

void StepperMotor::moveDegrees(int degreeNumber);
{
  if (degrees > 0){
    userAbs = (degreeNumber);
    stepNumber = (userAbs * 200/360);
    step(true,stepNumber);
 }
  if (degrees < 0){
    userAbs = (-1*degreesNumber);
    stepNumber = (userAbs * 200/360);
    step(false,stepNumber);
  }
}
```

the .h header file:

```
#ifndef StepperMotor_h
#define StepperMotor_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class StepperMotor
{
    public:
            StepperMotor(int pin1, int pin2);
     void moveDegrees(int degreeNumber);
    private:
     void stepDegrees(bool dir, int steps);
         int dirPin;
         int stepPin;
         float userAbs;
         float stepNumber;
};
#endif
```

When I am trying to implement my own library files. I am not sure if I need the "void" in this case but the same error comes up either way. What is causing this?

Comment: What do you think `void StepperMotor.moveDegrees(-180);` is supposed to do?

Comment: it will move a stepper motor "x" amount of degrees.

Comment: Okay. What if I want to have multiple `StepperMotors`? What would the syntax look like?

Comment: This code points to lack of basic understanding of how to create and use a  class. Going through these fundamental concepts in a textbook or an online tutorial will be more helpful than getting answer to this specific problem.

Comment: @RSahu is there any specific instance in the code that points to this "lack of basic understanding" so I can learn where to improve myself?

Comment: @Alan, `void StepperMotor.moveDegrees(-180);` is a glaring case. `StepperMotor(8,9);` is another one but not as bad.

Comment: @AndyG I am not sure what you mean, this is only built for one stepper motor which is all I need. That stepper motor is controlled by pins 8 and 9 which are in the 'void setup()' function.

Comment: @RSahu Thank you.

Comment: @Alan: What if I had a `Pin` class that wasn't as simple as a simple integer? Now I need 8 or 9 of them. How would I create 8 pins?

Answer (score 1):

Lets recap your code:

```
void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    void StepperMotor.moveDegrees(-180);
    delay(1000);
}
```

First thing first: Don't put `void` in the call to `moveDegress()` there.

Second:

The method `moveDegrees` is not static, therefore, you need an instance of the class `StepperMotor` in order to call it:

```
// note: you can initialize the variable here 
// but I'll  do it in setup
StepperMotor stepperMotorInstance; // your variable

void setup() {
    stepperMotorInstance = StepperMotor(8,9); // option 2: initialize variable in setup
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    stepperMotorInstance.moveDegrees(-180);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Hope it helps